# Как добавить флаг в JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

Добрый день, работаю с сервером на java в документации к нему говориться что следует для его запуска добавить в jvm флаг, дословно

> However, it is possible to connect to a remote KMS in other machine, simply adding the flag kms.url to the JVM executing the demo.

подскажите как это можно реализовать ?

Comment: Подозреваю, что к команде запуска надо добавить `-Dkms.url=<url>`.

Comment: Да точно но тогда на что же ругается maven ? Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Не понял причём тут сборщик. Но ругается он на то, что в каталоге, из которого вы его запускаете, нет файла pom.xml.

Comment: Нет не причём показалась что это взаимосвязано, поставьте пожалуйста в ответ ваш первый комментарий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К команде запуска надо добавить `-Dkms.url=<url>`